# Purge command deleting people's messages, including itself's

Tags: python, discord.py

Ive made a ghost ping command that pings someone for them to get online, but to avoid spamming, it deletes its own message once all the pings are done.
But the problem is, sometimes people send a message while its still pinging, then after its done, the person's message also gets deleted.
So how do i make the bot only purge it's own message?

heres the code

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx,member: discord.Member,amt): 
  for i in range(int(amt)):
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}")
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amt)+1)
```

Comment: Store the messages you send in a `list` and use `message.delete()` to remove only the specific ones that were sent. That way it doesn't even matter if your bot sends other messages (commands, ...) in between the pings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read [the documentation for `purge()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge)? It's quite clearly addressed there, and actually includes some helpful sample code you can use to accomplish such a task using the `check` parameter. Adapted to your code, it would look something like the following:

```
def is_me(m):
  return m.author == client.user

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx,member: discord.Member,amt): 
  for i in range(int(amt)):
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}")
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amt)+1, check=is_me)
```

Comment: The problem right now is that if 2 messages were sent in between, 2 ping messages wont get deleted. How do i solve that.

Comment: If that's the case, why not store the current `datetime` in a variable just before sending said messages, and use something like the `after` parameter to limit the messages that are `purge`d instead of the `limit` parameter itself? The documentation I've linked is very clear on how this works, where *specifically* are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the IDs of the messages sent, then use the [`channel.delete_messages`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.delete_messages) method:

```py
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx, member: discord.Member, amt):
    messages = []
    for i in range(int(amt)):
        m = await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}")
        messages.append(m.id)
    await ctx.channel.delete_messages(messages)
```